# How to avoid java.util.zip.ZipException in Android studio at build time

Tags: java, android

Do not suggest to clean build or `./gredlew` clean solution already tried a lot.

I simply want to avoid this error without excluding any jar file.

Error details

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException:
>   java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry:
>   android/support/v7/cardview/BuildConfig.class

Here is my Build.gradle dependencies

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile project(':material')
    compile project(':cardViewLib')
    compile ('com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3') {
        exclude module: 'com.android.support/v7/cardview/BuildConfig.class'
    }
}
```

Comment: Run ./gradlew -p <module_name> dependencies. Then post the results here. From I can see, you have two dependencies which are using different support-v7 library versions. (Well, the results must be quite big, so I guess, only the debug configuration will be sufficient to find what's causing the problem)

Comment: add your build.gradle file

Comment: added the build.gradle dependencies

Answer (score 0):

Here how I found the solution of this problem solving myself. First I removed material and cardview project which I was using as module. And then I added this into my build.gradle dependencies in direct as dependencies

Adding this

```
compile 'com.github.rey5137:material:1.2.2'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.1'
```

instead of using this

```
compile project(':material')
compile project(':cardViewLib')
```